# Remove all columns from datatable except for 25

Tags: c#, datatable

I have 500 Columns in my `DataTable` and I want to remove all of them except for 25 columns.

Is there any way to do this faster to save time and lines of code?

This is what I already tried:

```cs
private static void DeleteUselessColumns()
{
    //This is example data!
    List<DataColumn> dataColumnsToDelete = new List<DataColumn>();
    DataTable bigData = new DataTable();
    bigData.Columns.Add("Harry");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Konstantin");
    bigData.Columns.Add("George");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Gabriel");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Oscar");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Muhammad");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Emily");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Olivia");
    bigData.Columns.Add("Isla");
    
    List<string> columnsToKeep = new List<string>();
    columnsToKeep.Add("Isla");
    columnsToKeep.Add("Oscar");
    columnsToKeep.Add("Konstantin");
    columnsToKeep.Add("Gabriel");

    //This is the code i want to optimize------
    foreach (DataColumn column in bigData.Columns)
    {
        bool keepColumn = false;
        foreach (string s in columnsToKeep)
        {
            if (column.ColumnName.Equals(s))
            {
                keepColumn = true;
            }
        }
        if (!keepColumn)
        {
            dataColumnsToDelete.Add(column);
        }
    }
    
    foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in dataColumnsToDelete)
    {
        bigData.Columns.Remove(dataColumn);
    }
    //------------------------
}
```

Comment: By "faster" do you mean in less time or fewer lines of code? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The fastest way will be to not put the columns in your data table in the first place. Do you have control of how the table is populated?

Comment: Why is it slow?  Did you bench mark it?

Comment: How do you use this columnsToDelete. Can you show the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var columnsToKeep = new List<string>() { "Isla", "Oscar", "Konstantin", "Gabriel"};
    var toRemove = new List<DataColumn>();
    
    foreach(DataColumn column in bigData.Columns)
    {
      if (!columnsToKeep.Any(name => column.ColumnName == name ))
      {
         toRemove.Add(column);
      }
    }
    
    toRemove.ForEach(col => bigData.Columns.Remove(col));
```

Answer (score 0):

if they have different names create an array of string

```
var columns = new string[] { "Harry", "Konstantin","John"};
 var columnsToKeep = new string[] { "John", "Konstantin"};

    var columnsToDelete = from item in columns
                where !columnsToKeep.Contains(item)
                select item;
```

or using lambda

```
   var columnsToDelete = columns
                    .Where (i=> !columnsToKeep.Contains(i))
                    .ToList();
```

toDelete

```
Harry
```

Comment: No this is just an example, as i mentioned it will be 500 columns which have all have different names.

Answer (score 0):

Test1...test9 same code could be made a loop. No need to add the columns to delete in a list, just delete them in the first while loop. As for performance, not sure how to improve it.

You could try to use a DataView that selects the desired columns then copy to table. You need to experiment.

Comment: I don't want to hard code all 25 columns that i want to copy, do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Do they follow the same pattern?

Comment: No they are all different

Comment: What about those you want to keep?

Comment: I updated the code sorry for the misunderstanding. To answear you're question no.

Comment: Ok, based on what do you decide a column is needed? Is there any specific criterion other than the name? If not, then hardcoded the name of the columns to be kept can be used. You can initialize an array containing these columns.